# Intellisense not working golang test files

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Title says it all. I open a test file. Type `$package.`. Nothing comes up. It's not a delay issue. It's not an empty package. How do I get intellisense to turn on?

Update: I've open a bug ticket with the VSCode-Golang team. As we find more information, I'll report back here. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2278

Comment: Do you have by chance compilation directive in your test files like `// +build integration`? That can instruct tools to ignore file.

Comment: The only place with compilation directives is the vendor directory. Nothing in my immediate code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure as to the whys and the wherefores, but the solution was to reinstall all of the Go tools in VSCode. Look for "Go: Install/Update Tools". I selected them all. Once they installed,restart VScode. At this point autocomplete turned on.

I didn't remember a VSCode update before things broke. If you run into this issue, try reinstalling the tools within VScode.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your opened go file, the one you try to edit, is part of the open project folder in vs-code, otherwise the auto-completion will not work properly. If you want to edit file from other module it's better to open the module folder in other instance of vs-code and edit it from there.

Answer (score -1):

If the intellisense was already working and suddenly stops, you may try any of the below or both to resolve this.

1. Reset the VisualStudio settings as explained here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms247075(v=vs.90)
2. Delete the **.VS** folder from your project.

Comment: The problem is specific to test files. Intellisense works find in regular files. I found that activating the go language server helps go.useLanguageServer. Don't know why it's just the test files.

Comment: to clarify, I tried your advice, but was unable to get test file completion to work.