# How re-enable intellisense in VS Code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I know that a similar was asked on [Intellisense not working golang test files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54166042/intellisense-not-working-golang-test-files), but since I am new to VS Code I didn't quite understand the solution. Also since I have a low reputation I couldn't comment for help.

What I know about my problem is that on Ctrl + Space VSCode used to show the list of functions associated with the Golang package, but suddenly one day it stopped working.

Comment: This link might help - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go check if `go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages` is enabled as `true` in your vscode settings.

Comment: Can you try to uninstall "Go" extension in VS code and then reinstall it?

Comment: @Zoinks I had already done that but it didn't work. I even tried using the nightly version of the extension but still, it didn't work.

Comment: @Harshit it is set to true. Just to make sure I set it false and then changed it back to true, still no IntelliSense.

Comment: @Harshit can you  tell me if  [code]("python.languageServer": "Microsoft",) should be in my go extension's settings.json

Comment: The only thing that worked for me was to uninstall Go completely and re-install it (I used homebrew to re-install it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found out my answer. Apparently for some reason in my `settings.json` the line `"go.useLanguageServer": true,` wasn't there. After adding it VSCode told me to install something called `gopls` which fixed everything.

Comment: In my case the language server was running but I had not declared the folder I was working in in the go.work file. More information: https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md